# Codeigniter select box click get product details

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, dropdown

Am creating a **Billing System** using Codeigniter. Here i want to select product using `droupdown` that product details show without refresh the page like `ajax`. My code is following:

**View**

```
<?php
   foreach($productlists as $product)
   {
   ?>
<tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>
      <select class="form-control" name="product_id">
         <option>--Select Payment--</option>
         <option value="<?php echo $product['sno']; ?>"><?php echo $product['product_name']; ?></option>
      </select>
   </td>
   <td><input type="number" name="product_order_qty" class="form-control" value="1"></td>
   <td>0.8</td>
   <td>0.8</td>
   <td><input type="number" name="product_price" class="form-control" value="100"></td>
   <td><input type="number" name="product_total" class="form-control" value="101.60"></td>
   <td><a class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</a></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Ajax code here            
</script>
```

And Pass the product id to controller

**controller**

```
function productdetails()
{
    $id = $_GET['product_id'];
    $data['product'] = $this->orders->productdetails($id);
    $data['title'] = "View Customer Order";
    $this->load->view('customer_order_view',$data);
}
```

Please help me to pass the `product_id` using `Ajax`.
Thanks in advance

Comment: [Visit this link ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593137/ajax-with-select-box-in-codeigniter?rq=1)You can get the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select class="form-control" name="product_id" onchange="getProduct(this.value)">
     <option>--Select Payment--</option>
     <option value="<?php echo $product['sno']; ?>"><?php echo $product['product_name']; ?></option>
  </select> 

//your jquery function

function getProduct(product_id){

alert(product_id);

 $.ajax({
                url: "your_url",
                type: "POST",
                data:
                {
                  id:product_id,
                }
            }).done(function( data )
            {
                //  alert(data);

            });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer i don't `ajax` that's am asking this question. Can you please write the code for `ajax`...!

Comment: Thanks its working but value not pass to `controller`. And this is my URL`url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>customer_order/getproduct",`

Comment: you can get the value in controller by
$id = $this->input->post('id')

Comment: Bro post your answer here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45443363/codeigniter-select-box-value-not-pass-to-controller-using-ajax