# Codeigniter select box value not pass to controller using ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, dropdown

Am trying to pass the `select-box` value to `controller` but value not pass
This is my code

```
<select class="form-control" name="product_id" onchange="getProduct(this.value)">
    <option>--Select Payment--</option>
    <option value="<?php echo $product['sno']; ?>"><?php echo $product['product_name']; ?></option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getProduct(product_id) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>customer_order/getproduct",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            id: product_id,
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('product_id').val(data);
        alert(product_id);
    });
}

   </script>
```

Controller:

```
class Customer_order extends CI_Controller {
  function getproduct(){
   $data = $this->input->post('id');
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$data.'");</script>';
   $this->load->view('create_customer_order',$data);
  }
}
```

How can i pass the value to controller using ajax ?

Answer (score 1):

Pls do make some changes in ur code as follows

```
<select class="form-control" name="product_id" id="product_id">
    <option>--Select Payment--</option>
 <?php foreach($product as $prod){ ?>

     <option value="<?php echo $prod['sno']; ?>"><?php echo $prod['product_name']; ?></option>

<?php } ?>

</select>





<script>
$('#product_id').on('change', function(){
   var proId = $('#product_id option:selected').val();
 if(proId != null){

    var url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>customer_order/getproduct";
            var proResult = $.ajax({
                                            url: url,
                                            data: {'id': proId },
                                            type: 'post',
                                            dataType: 'json'
                                        });
                proResult.done(function(data){
//                 console.log('data', data);
//                 alert(data);
//                 Here..Do something as you wish

                });
 }
});

</script>
```

I think this is only the reference code for getting an idea about how to pass data to controller and return the result to the view page using ajax and json

In the controller there should be function

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Customer_order extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();


    }

    function getproduct() {
     $data = $this->input->post('id', true);
     header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
     echo(json_encode($data));

    }
} ?>
```

I hope this may helps you. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer Abdul Salam

Comment: Your welcome Ramesh... if this helpful pls tick as right answer..thnks

Comment: Sure bro i will check and tell you. And aslo am just click up vote to your answer

Comment: Bro not working how can i check data passing or not in contoller

Comment: Just uncomment console.log('data', data); in the script, and check the data